# What's the best tool for generating a parser in Java for my own language grammar?

Tags: java, parsing, programming-languages, antlr

I'm developing a small programming language based mostly of the C99 standard and I've already written a fairly decent lexer in java and now I'm looking to generate a Java Parser from the grammar. I know there's [Bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/), but that seems to only generate C code. I'm looking for a application that will allow me to input my grammar and create a full parser class in java code. Reading other SO posts on related topics, I've found ANTLR, but I'm wondering if anyone in the SO knows about a better tool?

thanks!

Comment: Nothing else was really mentioned here, and for good reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/611820/which-java-oriented-lexer-parser-for-simple-project-antlr-diy-etc

Comment: I forgot about Cup... nice find on the duplicate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another couple to look at are [JavaCC](https://javacc.dev.java.net/) and [SableCC](http://sablecc.org/) (it has been a long time since I looked at SableCC).

Comment: +1 for JavaCC.  It's been years since I used it but found it orders of magnitude easier than lex + yacc

Comment: I checked out JavaCC, but I'm not sure how it compares to ANTLR? What are the differences between the two? Is one simpler than the other and how?

Comment: It has been too long since I used JavaCC and I haven't used ANTLR enough to make a really fair comparison.  This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/382211/whats-better-antlr-or-javacc

Answer (score 2):

I've been quite impressed by [BNFC](http://www.cs.chalmers.se/Cs/Research/Language-technology/BNFC/), which is able to generate parsers in Java as well as in C, C++, C#, F#, Haskell, and OCaml.

Answer (score 0):

The JFlex home page at http://jflex.de indicates where to find Bison-like tools that can target Java:

http://byaccj.sourceforge.net/
http://www2.cs.tum.edu/projects/cup/
http://www.antlr.org/